# Majority Element Failing to close cycles

Tags: perl

I'm trying to figure out why this keeps printing the "majority element" candidate in every cycle.

The code I've been trying to make work is a Majority Element search (to find an element that is repeated more than half of the length of a list).

I can't separate the processes of finding the candidate and testing against the array because my input is a text file that has an indeterminate number of arrays. It's an exercise from [rosalind.info](http://rosalind.info/problems/locations/) that has different inputs every time you try to solve it.

An example of the input would be

```
-5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 -8 7 7 7 1 7 3 7 -7 1 6 5 10 100 1000 1 -5 1 6 7 1 1 10 1
```

Here's what I've written so far.

```
foreach my $currentrow (@lists) {

    my @row = ();
    @row = split( /\s/, $currentrow );

    my $length = $#row;
    my $count  = 0;
    my $i      = 0;

    for $i ( 0 .. $length - 1 ) {

        if ( $count == 0 ) {
            $candidate = $row[$i];
            $count++;
        }

        if ( ( $count > 0 ) and ( $i = $length - 1 ) ) {

            my $counter2 = 0;

            for my $j ( 0 .. $length - 1 ) {
                if ( $row[$j] == $candidate ) {
                    $counter2++;
                }
            }

            if ( $counter2 <= ( $#row / 2 ) and ( $i = $length - 1 ) ) {
                $candidate = -1;
                print $candidate, " ", $i, " ";
            }

            if ( $counter2 > ( $#row / 2 ) and ( $i = $length - 1 ) ) {
                print $candidate, " ", $i, " ";
            }

        }

        if ( $candidate == $row[$i] and $count > 0 ) {
            $count = $count + 1;
        }

        if ( $candidate != $row[$i] and $count > 0 ) {
            $count = $count - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some sample input, expected output and actual output

Comment: -5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
-8 7 7 7 1 7 3 7
-7 1 6 5 10 100 1000 1
-5 1 6 7 1 1 10 1 is the l input    5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 6 -1 6 7 6 7 6 7 6 -1 6 7 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6 -1 6  the o utput that i get =(

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why it keeps printing something in every iteration? :_  instead of only 5, 7, -1, -1, keeps printing strange things.

Comment: Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in place? I imagine that your problem may be because of the test `$i = $length - 1`, which is an *assignment*, and should be `$i == $length - 1`

Comment: YAAAY Thank you!!!! it worked!!! :DDD I'm a complete dork. Sorry, it's my first month trying to program. and i'm already old :p

Comment: You're welcome; it's a very common mistake. You must practise encouraging yourself: calling yourself names will soak into your attitude. Remind yourself that you couldn't even have considered this a month ago and reject the thoughts that tell you you're not progressing fast enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in place?

I imagine that your problem may be because of the test `$i = $length - 1`, which is an assignment, and should be `$i == $length - 1`

Answer (score 1):

To find a majority element I would use a hash:

```
perl -nae '%h=(); $h{$_}+=2 for @F; $h{$_}>@F and print for keys %h; print "\n"'
```

Each line of input is treated separately. Each line of output matches a line of input and presents its majority element or is empty if there is no such element.

Edit: Now the solution uses autosplit (`-a`), which is shorter and work not only for numbers.